# What is meaning of first byte of the hash modulo four

Tags: cassandra-2.0, datastax, cql3

I was going through [THIS](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/basic-rules-of-cassandra-data-modeling) and there is one example

```
CREATE TABLE groups (
    groupname text,
    username text,
    email text,
    age int,
    hash_prefix int,
    PRIMARY KEY ((groupname, hash_prefix), username)
)
```

> The new column, hash_prefix, holds a prefix of a hash of the username.
>   For example, it could be the first byte of the hash modulo four.
>   Together with groupname, these two columns form the compound partition
>   key. Instead of a group residing on one partition, it’s now spread
>   across four partitions.

Here what is meaning of `first byte of the hash modulo four`. Considering the given table can you give one example that what will be the query to sort & pagination ?

Comment: I was also following the same article and got lost in the table creation. May I know where do we define "hash_prefix" value so that I can change modulo value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It means the remainder of the first byte divided by 4.  A [Modulo operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation) is defined as:

> In computing, the modulo operation finds the remainder after division of one number by another (sometimes called modulus).

So for example, if the value of the first byte is 0xF7, that modulo four is 3.   You may have seen this as the '%' operator in java, python and other languages.  You can verify this in a python interpreter, i.e.:

> >>> 0xF7 % 4

yields 3.

Comment: So how will that help in given table to do sort & pagination. can you show the query for the same ? I mean i want to `select latest 100 user who joined group with pagination size 10`

Comment: It won't really.  By adding hash_prefix to the partition key, the data can now be stored in 4 different partitions, therefore distributing your data more evenly among your cluster (instead of possibly being hot on one partition).  Unfortunately, you will now need to make a query for each hash_prefix separately since it is part of the partition key.

Comment: consider the given table `groups`

Comment: so i cant fetch `latest 10 record` and also cant do `pagination` in this design ?

Comment: Not with a single query unless you use ALLOW FILTERING which is not recommended.  You would have to make 4 separate queries and then join your results to find the 10 newest.

Comment: Alternatively you could follow the strategy employed by 'group_join_dates' in the example to include the join date in the partition, and query by date in descending order until you've found 10 records.  It is likely you will have more than 10 signups in a single day if your rows are wide enough to be partitioned.

Comment: `You would have to make 4 separate queries and then join your results to find the 10 newest.` you mean soing separate SELECT query multiple times ?

Comment: Ah andy you pushed me to very interesting point whose answer i wnted to know since few days. In cassandra is it good to execute query on multiple table like        First Query:    `Select msgId, postedById from publishMsg`  then `select fullName from user_info where userId=<postedById from 1st query>`

Comment: That sounds reasonable to me.

Comment: But Cassandra is a distributed DB so dose making separate SELECT make sense ? Theoratically all your data should be in one table but practically its not possible e.g `Select id,name,title from TOPIC` Now to see whether a user is following a topic or not you will have to query other table `Select topicId from WHOFOLLOW where userId=X`